# Style the output of JSON in Zend Framework to make jQuery DataTables working

Tags: php, json, zend-framework, frameworks, datatables

I am trying to implement jQuery DataTables into a "new" form with Zend Framework, I set up the following action in the controller:

```
public function ajaxFindQuotesAction()
{
    $this        -> setNoRender();
    $quoteTable  =  new Model_QuotesTable();
    $select      =  $quoteTable->select();
    $select      -> from($quoteTable, array('qte_id', 'qte_description'));
    $rows        =  $quoteTable->fetchAll($select);
    $json        =  Zend_Json::encode($rows->toArray());
    echo($json);
}
```

I also set up in the view the following code:

```
<?php $this->inlineScript()->captureStart(); ?>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').dataTable( {
            "bProcessing": true,
            "sAjaxSource": '/jobs/ajax-find-quotes'
        } );
    } );
<?php $this->inlineScript()->captureEnd(); ?>

<table class="display dataTable" id="example" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Title</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
</table>
```

Problem is, the current JSON output is the following:

```
[
    {
        "column_1":"value 1",
        "column_2":"value 2"
    },
    {
        "qte_id":"3",
        "qte_description":"go to the zoo"
    }
]
```

While DataTables to work wants this format (copied from the example file):

```
{
  "aaData": [
    [
      "value 1",
      "value 2"
    ],
    [
      "Trident",
      "Internet Explorer 5.0"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Any ideas? Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$data = array_values(array_map('array_values', $rows->toArray()));
$json = Zend_Json::encode(array_combine(
            array('aaData'),
            array($data)
        ));
```

You need to encode an object, which consists of rows and fields as arrays. The problem is that PHP's so-called arrays are actually ordered maps, so you need to get rid of the associative keys to have arrays in resulting JSON.